# How to get the indices of the optimal basis using Gurobi through a C++ code

Tags: c++, linear-programming, gurobi

I am calling Gurobi through a c++ program to solve a linear program and I need to extract the indices of the optimal base.

```
#include "gurobi_c++.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
#include<vector> 

int
main(int   argc,
     char *argv[])
{
  try {
    GRBEnv env = GRBEnv();
    GRBModel model = GRBModel(env);

    // Create variables

    GRBVar x1 = model.addVar(0.0, GRB_INFINITY , 0.0, GRB_CONTINUOUS, "x1");
    GRBVar x2 = model.addVar(0.0, GRB_INFINITY , 0.0, GRB_CONTINUOUS, "x2");

    // Set objective

    // model.setObjective(4 * x1 + 6 * x2, GRB_MAXIMIZE);
    model.setObjective(2 * x1 - 5 * x2, GRB_MAXIMIZE);

    // Add constraints

    model.addConstr(2 * x1 + 3 * x2 <= 30, "c0");

    model.addConstr(4 * x1 - 9 * x2 <= 0, "c1");

    model.addConstr(x1 + x2 >= 5, "c2");

    // Optimize model

    model.optimize();

    //get the indices of the optimal base
    int nbColumns = 3;
    int nbLines = 2;
    int * bhead = (int *) malloc (nbLines); 
     for (int i = 0; i < nbLines; ++i)
    {
    bhead[i] = -1;
    }
    

    GRBModel *p_model = &model;

    int b = GRBgetBasisHead(p_model, bhead);

    cout<<"base 1"<<bhead[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"base 2"<<bhead[1]<<endl;;
    cout<<"base 3"<<bhead[2]<<endl;

  } catch(GRBException e) {
    cout << "Error code = " << e.getErrorCode() << endl;
    cout << e.getMessage() << endl;
  } catch(...) {
    cout << "Exception during optimization" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I get an error when I try to use `GRBgetBasisHead` which is defined in the C API, the error is:

```
error: cannot convert ‘GRBModel*’ to ‘GRBmodel* {aka _GRBmodel*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int GRBgetBasisHead(GRBmodel*, int*)’
```

Because in C++ API the models are constructed using `GRBModel` and in C API the models are constructed using `GRBmodel`. In the other hand, there is `VBasis` that gives the status of a variable in the current basis, but in this case we need to test the status of all the variables to find the indices of the optimal base. My question is: is there a way to get directly the indices of the optimal base?

Answer (score 0):

Gurobi ships the C++ API source code as part of their distribution (in linux64/src/cpp). I assume that you compiled this? If so, just change the visibility of the `Cmodel` field in Model.h so that you can access it. It's at the top of the file in the private members area. Or you could add wrapper methods for the advanced simplex routines.